# Google maps Api - A place between two points

Tags: api, google-maps, elixir

I've never used the google api before, but over lunch I was trying to think of a fun weekend project. I'm trying to learn Elixir. So I thought to myself, I would like to find a random place between two given locations with the google api.

Here's the problem. I work on an app during the week and every Thursday we have a team lunch. We can never decide which restaurant to go to in town. I'd like to build an app to which I can input two separate locations and between those locations it will pick a random restaurant. I believe I can do this with the Google Api but I've never used it before and I'm not sure where to start?

So, Here is my question... With the given information, is this possible? and what google api should I use to accomplish this? I'm not necessarily asking for code just Some helpful hints on where to begin. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes.

You would need to obviously define the two points you wish for your "query".

Then you can define (there are other ways) a circle for each point with a radius equal to the distance of the two points.

Then you will need to select all the points of interests in the circles and calculate the distance of that point of interest to both the points (you could add the distance).

Finally you would need to sort the points of interest based on the distance you calculated.

From here on, you can work with a random number to pick restaurants within acceptable total distance between the two points.

Note 1: There are other ways of doing it like defining a rectangular region derived by the two points but you will need to add buffers to ensure it doesn't before too small and I think may have other failure points too.

Note 2: You may end up needing to define two rectangular regions (one for each point) to search against but I am pretty sure Google supports circles from what I recall.

Note 3: I am assuming you will have the layers (with restaurants) enabled in Google maps before you do the above. If no layers, you would at very minimum perform a general "restaurants" query (programmatically) to populate the map and then search on that layer.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! For the help